# RecyclerView Item doesn't fit when using CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

In RecyclerView in xml design
How do I fully display the last text?

[image: Here the Image]

When you see the image, you will notice that the last text (TextView)
Only a small part of it is visible and the rest of the text is hidden on the screen

Here is my list_item xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="72dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingBottom="16dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/text2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my activity_main xml

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="168dp"
    android:background="?colorPrimary">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="72dp"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:contentInsetStart="72dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_action_menu" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

thanks for your support

Comment: try giving a margin-bottom of 10dp it might help, please let me know if it works

Comment: I did that
It didn't work

Comment: ok have you used **`layout_below="@id/app_bar_layout"`** ? it might help because the app bar is also overlapping the recycler view and its matching the parent so it might be the problem!

Comment: I did that
It didn't work

Comment: having a responsive UI is a very important job
https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes
https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout